# python pandas: trying to vectorize a function using date_range

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, numba

Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'KEY': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2],
    'START_DATE': ['2018-01-05', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-23', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-11'],
    'STOP_DATE': ['2018-01-22', '2018-03-10', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-15', '2018-04-01', '2018-07-21'],
    'AMOUNT': [5, 3, 11, 14, 7, 9],
    })
df.START_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.START_DATE, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.STOP_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.STOP_DATE, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df
>>>   AMOUNT KEY  START_DATE  STOP_DATE
0       5     A   2018-01-05  2018-01-22
1       3     B   2018-01-04  2018-03-10
2      11     C   2018-01-01  2018-01-31
3      14     A   2018-01-23  2018-02-15
4       7     A   2018-02-01  2018-04-01
5       9     B   2018-03-11  2018-07-21
```

I am trying to get the `AMOUNT` per month and per `KEY` considering the `AMOUNT` as linearly distributed (by day) between `START_DATE` and `STOP_DATE`. The output is shown below. I would like to also keep track of the number of charged days in a month. For example `KEY = A` has overlapped periods in February so the number of charged periods can be > 28.

```
            DAYS   AMOUNT
A 2018_01    27  10.250000
  2018_02    43  12.016667
  2018_03    31   3.616667
  2018_04     1   0.116667
B 2018_01    28   1.272727
  2018_02    28   1.272727
  2018_03    31   1.875598
  2018_04    30   2.030075
  2018_05    31   2.097744
  2018_06    30   2.030075
  2018_07    21   1.421053
C 2018_01    31  11.000000
  2018_02     0   0.000000
```

I came up with the solution detailed below but it is highly inefficient and takes an unaffordable amount of time to run for a dataset with ~100 million rows. I am looking for an improved version but could not manage to vectorize the `pd.date_range` part of it. Not sure if `numba` @jit could help here? Added a tag just in case.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
# Prepare the final dataframe (filled with zeros)
bounds = df.groupby('KEY').agg({'START_DATE': min, 'STOP_DATE':max}).reset_index()
multiindex = []
for row in bounds.itertuples():
    dates = pd.date_range(start=row.START_DATE, end=row.STOP_DATE + MonthEnd(),
                          freq='M').strftime('%Y_%m')
    multiindex.extend([(row.KEY, date) for date in dates])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(multiindex)
final = pd.DataFrame(0, index=index, columns=['DAYS', 'AMOUNT'])

# Run the actual iteration over rows
df['TOTAL_DAYS'] = (df.STOP_DATE - df.START_DATE).dt.days + 1
for row in df.itertuples():
    data = pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(start=row.START_DATE, end=row.STOP_DATE))
    data = data.resample('MS').size().rename('DAYS').to_frame()
    data['AMOUNT'] = data.DAYS / row.TOTAL_DAYS * row.AMOUNT
    data.index = data.index.strftime('%Y_%m')
    # Add data to the final dataframe
    final.loc[(row.KEY, data.index.tolist()), 'DAYS'] += data.DAYS.values
    final.loc[(row.KEY, data.index.tolist()), 'AMOUNT'] += data.AMOUNT.values
```

Comment: Maybe this SO answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047020/5805262. I need to investigate that.

Comment: This seems very similar to the issue I posted about a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291682/pandas-efficiently-converting-from-timespan-dataframe-to-year-month-enumerated). I still haven't found anything good yet.

Comment: I came up with something acceptable for my problem. Maybe this can inspire you for yours.

Comment: Thanks, this does work. On 100,000 rows it speeds everything up by 35%. Not amazing, but at least it's only 3 hours instead of 4. Probably the apply line that's still killing it.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually came up with this solution (heavily inspired from @jezrael answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047020/5805262)). Probably not the most memory efficient solution but this is not a major concern for me, execution time was the problem!

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin

df['ID'] = range(len(df))
df['TOTAL_DAYS'] = (df.STOP_DATE - df.START_DATE).dt.days + 1
df
>>>   AMOUNT KEY  START_DATE  STOP_DATE   ID  TOTAL_DAYS
0       5     A   2018-01-05  2018-01-22   0      18
1       3     B   2018-01-04  2018-03-10   1      66
2      11     C   2018-01-01  2018-01-31   2      31
3      14     A   2018-01-23  2018-02-15   3      24
4       7     A   2018-02-01  2018-04-01   4      60
5       9     B   2018-03-11  2018-07-21   5     133

final = (df[['ID', 'START_DATE', 'STOP_DATE']].set_index('ID').stack()
           .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
           .rename('DATE_AFTER')
           .to_frame())
final = final.groupby('ID').apply(
    lambda x: x.set_index('DATE_AFTER').resample('M').asfreq()).reset_index()
final = final.merge(df[['ID', 'KEY', 'AMOUNT', 'TOTAL_DAYS']], how='left', on=['ID'])
final['PERIOD'] = final.DATE_AFTER.dt.to_period('M')
final['DATE_BEFORE'] = final.DATE_AFTER - MonthBegin()
```

At this point `final` looks like this:

```
final
>>> ID DATE_AFTER KEY  AMOUNT  TOTAL_DAYS  PERIOD DATE_BEFORE
0    0 2018-01-31   A       5          18 2018-01  2018-01-01
1    1 2018-01-31   B       3          66 2018-01  2018-01-01
2    1 2018-02-28   B       3          66 2018-02  2018-02-01
3    1 2018-03-31   B       3          66 2018-03  2018-03-01
4    2 2018-01-31   C      11          31 2018-01  2018-01-01
5    3 2018-01-31   A      14          24 2018-01  2018-01-01
6    3 2018-02-28   A      14          24 2018-02  2018-02-01
7    4 2018-02-28   A       7          60 2018-02  2018-02-01
8    4 2018-03-31   A       7          60 2018-03  2018-03-01
9    4 2018-04-30   A       7          60 2018-04  2018-04-01
10   5 2018-03-31   B       9         133 2018-03  2018-03-01
11   5 2018-04-30   B       9         133 2018-04  2018-04-01
12   5 2018-05-31   B       9         133 2018-05  2018-05-01
13   5 2018-06-30   B       9         133 2018-06  2018-06-01
14   5 2018-07-31   B       9         133 2018-07  2018-07-01
```

We then merge back the initial `df` twice (start and end of month):

```
final = pd.merge(
    final,
    df[['ID', 'STOP_DATE']].assign(PERIOD = df.STOP_DATE.dt.to_period('M')),
how='left', on=['ID', 'PERIOD'])

final = pd.merge(
    final,
    df[['ID', 'START_DATE']].assign(PERIOD = df.START_DATE.dt.to_period('M')),
how='left', on=['ID', 'PERIOD'])

final['STOP_DATE'] = final.STOP_DATE.combine_first(final.DATE_AFTER)
final['START_DATE'] = final.START_DATE.combine_first(final.DATE_BEFORE)

final['DAYS'] = (final.STOP_DATE- final.START_DATE).dt.days + 1

final = final.drop(columns=['ID', 'DATE_AFTER', 'DATE_BEFORE'])
final.AMOUNT *= final.DAYS/final.TOTAL_DAYS
final = final.groupby(['KEY', 'PERIOD']).agg({'AMOUNT': sum, 'DAYS': sum})
```

With the expected result:

```
             AMOUNT     DAYS
KEY PERIOD                  
A   2018-01  10.250000    27   
    2018-02  12.016667    43
    2018-03   3.616667    31
    2018-04   0.116667     1
B   2018-01   1.272727    28
    2018-02   1.272727    28
    2018-03   1.875598    31
    2018-04   2.030075    30
    2018-05   2.097744    31
    2018-06   2.030075    30
    2018-07   1.421053    21
C   2018-01  11.000000    31
```