# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframe like this.

```
df1
MainId,Time,info1,info2
100,2018-07-12 08:05:00,a,b
100,2018-07-12 08:07:00,x,y
101,2018-07-14 16:00,c,d
100,2018-07-14 19:30:00,d,e
104,2018-07-14 03:30:00,g,h
```

and

```
df2
Id,MainId,startTime,endTime,value
1,100,2018-07-12 08:00:00,2018-07-12 08:10:00,1001
2,150,2018-07-14 10:05:00,2018-07-14 17:05:00,1002
3,101,2018-07-12 0:05:00,2018-07-12 19:05:00,1003
4,100,2018-07-12 08:05:00,2018-07-12 08:15:00,1004
```

`df2` is main dataframe and `df1` is subdataframe. I would like to check `starttime` and `endtime` of `df2` with the time in `df1` with respective to `MainId`. If `df1.Time isin df2(start and endtime)` with respective to `MainId`, then i  want to include `info1` and `info2` column of df1 to df2. If there are no values, then I would like to enter just nan.

I want my output like this

```
Id,MainId,info1,info2,value
1,100,a,b,1001
1,100,x,y,1001
2,150,nan,nan,1002
3,101,nan,nan,1003
4,100,a,b,1004
4,100,x,y,1004
```

Here I have two same Id(In Id1) and MainId in output because they have different info1 and info2 and I want to include that one too.

This is what I am doing in pandas

```
df2['info1'] = np.where((df2['MainId'] == df1['MainId'])& (df1['Time'].isin([df2['startTime'], df2['endTime']])),df1['info1'], np.nan)
```

but it is throwing an error

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

How Can i Fix this error ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: You should merge `on=MainId` and then use a boolean mask afterwards to find where the time is between. It's very similar to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755268/pandas-merge-on-datetime-or-datetime-in-datetimeindex), though in this case you just merge based on `MainId`

Comment: @ALollz I did trying first with `merge` but problem I found is that, after merge, while selecting the data when the Time isin (start and end), it is possible that some of the original data from `df2` were missing. I need to return all the data from `df2` ( expected output from question)

Answer (score 0):

`df1` and `df2` have diferente `Index` (you can check this by inspecting `df1.index` and `df2.index`. Hence, when you do `df2['MainId'] == df1['MainId']`, you have 2 series objects that are not comparable.

Try using a left join, something like:

```
df3 = df2.join(df1.set_index('MainId'), on='MainId'))
```

should give you the dataframe you want. You can then use it to execute your comparisons.

Comment: I am not sure, if merging dataframe would be a good solution in this case.

Comment: Why not? You will need to do that some way or another.