# Apply function for specific months and days in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have daily data from 2010 until 2020:

```
Ex:

Date            col1

2010-01-01      False
2010-01-02      False
...

2020-12-31      False
```

I want to set col1 = True for all rows, where (month is equal 4 and day is bigger than 25) and month is equal to 5 and day is less then 5. So basically it means, that for all dates between 25th day of the 4th month and 5th day of the 5th month I want to set col1 = True.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688364/efficiently-check-if-dataframe-has-date-between-a-range-and-return-a-count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.dt.month` and `.dt.day` to access `month` and `day` from the date and then create the conditions from that:

```
df.loc[
  ((df.Date.dt.month == 4) & (df.Date.dt.day > 25)) | 
  ((df.Date.dt.month == 5) & (df.Date.dt.day < 5)), 
'col1'] = True
```

Assume your `Date` is already datetime type, if not, you can use following to convert:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Comment: +10, i think this does work for the given bounds, but would probably get unwieldy with other ranges like 04-25 to 08-05 (since the inner months would have no day restrictions?)

Comment: i guess 04-25 to 08-05 would be something like `((df.Date.dt.month == 4) & (df.Date.dt.day > 25)) | (df.Date.dt.month > 4) | (df.Date.dt.month < 8) | ((df.Date.dt.month == 8) & (df.Date.dt.day < 5))`

Comment: @tdy Yeah, in that case we can add another or condition to say `df.Date.dt.month.between(5, 7)`. Might not be the most concise though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean index and assign it to a new column in your dataframe.

To find rows where the value of `Date` is between two other values, you can use the `between` method. `between` can take an argument `inclusive` that can be any of `"both"`, `"neither"`, `"left"`, or `"right"`. Use this to dial in the exact interval you want.

To ignore the year and only compare on month and day, if the column is of the dtype `datetime64`, you can use the `dt` accessor and use `strftime` to get just the month and day as a string and compare using lexicographic ordering:

```py
col1 = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d').between(
    '04-25', 
    '05-05', 
    inclusive="neither"
)
```

To add the boolean index to your dataframe:

```py
df['col1'] = col1
```

To only set the values in `'col1'` for the matching rows, per @tdy in the comments:

```py
df.loc[col1, 'col1'] = True
```

Comment: Ah, I re-read your question and it looks like you want to compare just the month and day, not the year. Editing again.

Comment: yeah, that's what's stumping me too.

Comment: Edited with a new solution.

Comment: ah +10, i think this does work and is much simpler than my `groupby` method

Comment: however note that this modifies the whole column. if you want to **only** set the matching dates to `True` without changing the other values, use `loc` or `mask`: `df[col1, 'col1'] = True` or `df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(col1, True)`

Comment: Good point @tdy, added