# Python Pandas: Trying to speed-up a per row per date in date_range operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe of the following form where each row corresponds to a job run on a machine:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MachineID': [4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3],
    'JobStartDate': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-03'], 
    'JobEndDate': ['2020-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-04'], 
    'IsTypeAJob': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
    })
    
df
>>>    MachineID JobStartDate JobEndDate  IsTypeAJob
0          4      2020-01-01  2020-01-03      1
1          3      2020-01-01  2020-01-03      1
2          2      2020-01-01  2020-01-04      0
3          2      2020-01-01  2020-01-02      1
4          1      2020-01-02  2020-01-04      0
5          1      2020-01-03  2020-01-05      0
6          5      2020-01-01  2020-01-02      1
7          3      2020-01-03  2020-01-04      1
```

In my data there are two types of jobs that can be run on a machine, either type `A` or type `B`. My goal is to count the number of type `A` and type `B` jobs per machine per day. Thus the desired result would look something like

```
        MachineID    Date         TypeAJobs  TypeBJobs
0           1     2020-01-02          0          1
1           1     2020-01-03          0          2
2           1     2020-01-04          0          2
3           1     2020-01-05          0          1
4           2     2020-01-01          1          1
5           2     2020-01-02          1          1
6           2     2020-01-03          0          1
7           2     2020-01-04          0          1
8           3     2020-01-01          1          0
9           3     2020-01-02          1          0
10          3     2020-01-03          2          0
11          3     2020-01-04          1          0
12          4     2020-01-01          1          0
13          4     2020-01-02          1          0
14          4     2020-01-03          1          0
15          5     2020-01-01          1          0
16          5     2020-01-02          1          0
```

I have tried approaches found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046329/vectorized-implementation-to-create-multiple-rows-from-a-single-row-in-pandas-da/37047020#37047020) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481064/python-pandas-trying-to-vectorize-a-function-using-date-range/49491777#49491777) with a `resample()` and `apply()` method, but the computing time is too slow. This has to do with the fact that some date ranges span multiple years in my set, meaning one row can blow up into 2000+ new rows during resampling (my data contains around a million rows to begin with). Thus something like creating a new machine/date row for each date in the range of a certain job is too slow (with the goal of doing a `group_by(['MachineID', 'Date']).sum()` at the end).

I am currently thinking about a new approach where I begin by grouping by `MachineID` then finding the earliest job start date and latest job end date for that machine. Then I could create a date range of days between these two dates (incrementing by day) which I would use to index a new per machine data frame. Then for each job for that `MachineID` I could potentially sum over a range of dates, ie in pseudocode:

`df['TypeAJobs'][row['JobStartDate']:row['JobEndDate']] += 1` if it is a type `A` job or

`df['TypeBJobs'][row['JobStartDate']:row['JobEndDate']] += 1` otherwise.

This seems like it would avoid creating a bunch of extra rows for each job as now we are creating extra rows for each machine. Furthermore, the addition operations seem like they would be fast since we are adding to an entire slice of a series at once. However, I don't know if something like this (indexing by date) is possible in Pandas. Maybe there is some conversion that can be done first? After doing the above, ideally I would have a number of data frames similar to the desired result but only with one `MachineID`, then I would concatenate these data frames to get the result.

I would love to hear any suggestions about the feasibility/effectiveness of this approach or another potential algorithm. Thanks so much for reading!

Comment: Well written first question, with input, expected output, what you read before asking, and what you tried!

Comment: Cheers, thank you for your answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do the job, the idea is similar to use `str.get_dummies` on both columns start and end, but done with array broadcasting. Use `cumsum` do get one between start and end and 0 otherwise. Create a dataframe with the columns as dates and the index as both Machine and Type. Then do similar operation than the answer from [@Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971521/9274732) to get the expected output shape.

```
#get all possible dates
dr = pd.date_range(df['JobStartDate'].min(), 
                   df['JobEndDate'].max()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_numpy()

df_ = (pd.DataFrame(
            np.cumsum((df['JobStartDate'].to_numpy()[:, None] == dr).astype(int) 
                       - np.pad(df['JobEndDate'].to_numpy()[:, None]==dr,((0,0),(1,False)), 
                                mode='constant')[:, :-1],  # pad is equivalent to shift along columns
                      axis=1), 
            index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['MachineID', 'IsTypeAJob']]), 
            columns=dr,)
         .sum(level=['MachineID', 'IsTypeAJob']) #equivalent to groupby(['MachineID', 'IsTypeAJob']).sum()
         .replace(0, np.nan) #to remove extra dates per original row during the stack
         .stack()
         .unstack(level='IsTypeAJob', fill_value=0)
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
         .rename(columns={'level_1':'Date', 0:'TypeBJobs', 1:'TypeAJobs'})
      )
```

and you get

```
    MachineID        Date  TypeBJobs  TypeAJobs
0           1  2020-01-02          1          0
1           1  2020-01-03          2          0
2           1  2020-01-04          2          0
3           1  2020-01-05          1          0
4           2  2020-01-01          1          1
5           2  2020-01-02          1          1
6           2  2020-01-03          1          0
7           2  2020-01-04          1          0
8           3  2020-01-01          0          1
9           3  2020-01-02          0          1
10          3  2020-01-03          0          2
11          3  2020-01-04          0          1
12          4  2020-01-01          0          1
13          4  2020-01-02          0          1
14          4  2020-01-03          0          1
15          5  2020-01-01          0          1
16          5  2020-01-02          0          1
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer! Sorry if I am missing something obvious, but what does `dr` refer to in your code snippet? I know numpy can give some excellent speed-ups, so I am excited to try this out!

Comment: @Parados my bad, it was in another cell in my notebook. I edited

Comment: This approach is really something neat. The speed is about the same as the approach above on a toy version of my data (which only has jobs that span a short date range), but I have a feeling this will work well when I run into the longer term jobs. Unfortunately I can't actually run this on the full set without my Docker container running out of memory, but I will update as soon as I get set up on a better computer.

Comment: @Parados you are right, most of the time, on small data sample, using pandas methods are not really efficient because of overhead of using them. for your memory pb, what you can try is using `astype('int8')` for the first astype, that may save some memory as by default, astype(int) is int32 and it this case int8 is enough :)

Comment: Incredible. This approach took my run time from 3 hours down to 10 minutes. With the help of `astype('int8')` I was even able to watch some Netflix while it was running. I also opted to use `Freq='MS'` in the `date_range` to group by month, which dropped the time down to 26 seconds with your answer (as opposed to 6 minutes with `apply` approaches). I ran a diff on the outputs and everything matches up. Hats off to you sir.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, try using `pd.date_range` and `explode` to create 'daily' rows, then groupby dates and IsTypeAJob and `rename` columns:

```
df_out = df.assign(JobDates=df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['JobStartDate'], 
                                                             x['JobEndDate'], freq='D'), 
                                     axis=1))\
           .explode('JobDates')

df_out = df_out.groupby([df_out['MachineID'], 
                         df_out['JobDates'].dt.floor('D'), 
                         'IsTypeAJob'])['MachineID'].count()\
               .unstack()\
               .rename(columns={0:'TypeBJobs', 1:'TypeAJobs'})\
               .fillna(0).reset_index()

df_out
```

Output:

```
IsTypeAJob  MachineID   JobDates  TypeBJobs  TypeAJobs
0                   1 2020-01-02        1.0        0.0
1                   1 2020-01-03        2.0        0.0
2                   1 2020-01-04        2.0        0.0
3                   1 2020-01-05        1.0        0.0
4                   2 2020-01-01        1.0        1.0
5                   2 2020-01-02        1.0        1.0
6                   2 2020-01-03        1.0        0.0
7                   2 2020-01-04        1.0        0.0
8                   3 2020-01-01        0.0        1.0
9                   3 2020-01-02        0.0        1.0
10                  3 2020-01-03        0.0        2.0
11                  3 2020-01-04        0.0        1.0
12                  4 2020-01-01        0.0        1.0
13                  4 2020-01-02        0.0        1.0
14                  4 2020-01-03        0.0        1.0
15                  5 2020-01-01        0.0        1.0
16                  5 2020-01-02        0.0        1.0
```

---

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'JobDates':pd.date_range(r.JobStartDate, r.JobEndDate, freq='D'),
                        'MachineID':r.MachineID, 
                        'IsTypeAJob':r.IsTypeAJob}) for i, r in df.iterrows()])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Going to try running this now.

Comment: `explode` gave me a 15% speed-up but it looks like the slow step is still expanding by job rather than by machine. Do you think there is any way around creating the date range per row?

Comment: Yes, we can do this differently and add speed.  However, I am away from my computer for an couple of hours.... Maybe someone else can help, otherwise I will revisit when I get back to my computer.