# pandas multiple date ranges from column of dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Current df:

```
ID  Date
11  3/19/2018
22  1/5/2018
33  2/12/2018
..  ..
```

I have the df with ID and Date. ID is unique in the original df.
I would like to create a new df based on date. Each ID has a Max Date, I would like to use that date and go back 4 days(5 rows each ID)
There are thousands of IDs.

Expect to get:

```
ID  Date
11  3/15/2018
11  3/16/2018
11  3/17/2018
11  3/18/2018
11  3/19/2018
22  1/1/2018
22  1/2/2018
22  1/3/2018
22  1/4/2018
22  1/5/2018
33  2/8/2018
33  2/9/2018
33  2/10/2018
33  2/11/2018
33  2/12/2018
…   …
```

I tried the following method, i think use `date_range` might be right direction, but I keep get error.

pd.date_range

```
def date_list(row):
    list = pd.date_range(row["Date"], periods=5)
    return list

df["Date_list"] = df.apply(date_list, axis = "columns")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group by `ID`, select the column `Date`, and for each group generate a series of five days leading up to the greatest date.

rather than writing a long lambda, I've written a helper function.

```
def drange(x): 
    e = x.max()
    s = e-pd.Timedelta(days=4)
    return pd.Series(pd.date_range(s,e))

res = df.groupby('ID').Date.apply(drange)
```

Then drop the extraneous level from the resulting multiindex and we get our desired output

```
res.reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
# outputs:

    ID       Date
0   11 2018-03-15
1   11 2018-03-16
2   11 2018-03-17
3   11 2018-03-18
4   11 2018-03-19
5   22 2018-01-01
6   22 2018-01-02
7   22 2018-01-03
8   22 2018-01-04
9   22 2018-01-05
10  33 2018-02-08
11  33 2018-02-09
12  33 2018-02-10
13  33 2018-02-11
14  33 2018-02-12
```

---

**Compact alternative**

```
# Help function to return Serie with daterange
func = lambda x: pd.date_range(x.iloc[0]-pd.Timedelta(days=4), x.iloc[0]).to_series()

res = df.groupby('ID').Date.apply(func).reset_index().drop('level_1',1)
```

Comment: Nice solution. You could even use iloc[0] to retrieve first value (as they are unique in this case). I added it in... but tbh I think your solution might be good as it is!

Answer (score 4):

#### `reindex`ing with `pd.date_range`

Let's try creating a flat list of date-ranges and reindexing this DataFrame.

```
from itertools import chain

v = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)).set_index('Date')
# assuming ID is a string column
v.reindex(chain.from_iterable(
    pd.date_range(end=i, periods=5) for i in v.index)
).bfill().reset_index()  

         Date  ID
0  2018-03-14  11
1  2018-03-15  11
2  2018-03-16  11
3  2018-03-17  11
4  2018-03-18  11
5  2018-03-19  11
6  2017-12-31  22
7  2018-01-01  22
8  2018-01-02  22
9  2018-01-03  22
10 2018-01-04  22
11 2018-01-05  22
12 2018-02-07  33
13 2018-02-08  33
14 2018-02-09  33
15 2018-02-10  33
16 2018-02-11  33
17 2018-02-12  33
```

---

#### `concat` based solution on `keys`

Just for fun. My `reindex` solution is definitely more performant and easier to read, so if you were to pick one, use that.

```
v = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date))
v_dict = {
    j : pd.DataFrame(
            pd.date_range(end=i, periods=5), columns=['Date']
        ) 
    for j, i in zip(v.ID, v.Date)
}

(pd.concat(v_dict, axis=0)
  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
  .rename_axis('ID')
  .reset_index()
)

    ID       Date
0   11 2018-03-14
1   11 2018-03-15
2   11 2018-03-16
3   11 2018-03-17
4   11 2018-03-18
5   11 2018-03-19
6   22 2017-12-31
7   22 2018-01-01
8   22 2018-01-02
9   22 2018-01-03
10  22 2018-01-04
11  22 2018-01-05
12  33 2018-02-07
13  33 2018-02-08
14  33 2018-02-09
15  33 2018-02-10
16  33 2018-02-11
17  33 2018-02-12
```

Comment: Amazing. +1. Is it possible without using chain?

Comment: @HarvIpan You mean without a loop at all? Hmm, I would be interested to see. Let me try.

Comment: @coldspeed, yeah. May be a long shot without looping as it is not a traditional reindexing problem for dates.

Comment: @HarvIpan Drawing a blank here. This really is a challenging problem.

Comment: Nice solution. But why would we need to encapsulate the chain iterable to a list?

Comment: @HarvIpan If you're willing to create a second date column by subtracting 4 days, then jezrael's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046329/vectorized-implementation-to-create-multiple-rows-from-a-single-row-in-pandas-da) allows you to do it with some stacking and a groupby

Comment: @AntonvBR I am surprised it works without! Thank you! By the way, you've a nice solution as well, +1 :)

Comment: It's nice with options but your second solution just seems like too much code for something (when you already have a working solution). (And not any speed gain!). Impressive though

Comment: @ALollz, bingo! I like that approach.

Comment: @AntonvBR yeaaaah, was just trying different things... seeing what works out. The second solution is _bad_, but it is a solution. Anyway.

Comment: Maybe `pd.date_range(end=x,periods=5)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another by using `df.assign` to overwrite `date` and `pd.concat` to glue the range together. cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution wins in performance but I think this might be a nice addition as it is quite easy to read and understand.

```
df = pd.concat([df.assign(Date=df.Date - pd.Timedelta(days=i)) for i in range(5)])
```

Alternative:

```
dates = (pd.date_range(*x) for x in zip(df['Date']-pd.Timedelta(days=4), df['Date']))

df = (pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df['ID'],dates)))
        .T
        .stack()
        .reset_index(0)
        .rename(columns={'level_0': 'ID', 0: 'Date'}))
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
ID  Date
11  3/19/2018
22  1/5/2018
33  2/12/2018'''

# Recreate dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df = pd.concat([df.assign(Date=df.Date - pd.Timedelta(days=i)) for i in range(5)])
df.sort_values(by=['ID','Date'], ascending = [True,True], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   ID       Date
0  11 2018-03-15
0  11 2018-03-16
0  11 2018-03-17
0  11 2018-03-18
0  11 2018-03-19
1  22 2018-01-01
1  22 2018-01-02
1  22 2018-01-03
1  22 2018-01-04
1  22 2018-01-05
2  33 2018-02-08
2  33 2018-02-09
2  33 2018-02-10
2  33 2018-02-11
2  33 2018-02-12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `groupby` with `date_range`

```
df.groupby('ID').Date.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(pd.date_range(end=x.iloc[0],periods=5))).reset_index(level=0)
Out[793]: 
   ID       Date
0  11 2018-03-15
1  11 2018-03-16
2  11 2018-03-17
3  11 2018-03-18
4  11 2018-03-19
0  22 2018-01-01
1  22 2018-01-02
2  22 2018-01-03
3  22 2018-01-04
4  22 2018-01-05
0  33 2018-02-08
1  33 2018-02-09
2  33 2018-02-10
3  33 2018-02-11
4  33 2018-02-12
```

Comment: this is essentially the same approach i took, but i like how you specify the end and periods

Comment: @HaleemurAli yep , I just notice almost the same :-)